# Which operator topology to use and how to see map is continuous

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, vector-bundles

This question is from a passage in the beginning of Atiyah's K-Theory notes.

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space and $E=X \times V$ and $F= X \times W$ are two product bundles, where $V$ and $W$ are topological, finite dimensional vector spaces. Clearly, a bundle homomorphism $\phi: E \to F$ corresponds to a map $\Phi: X \to \mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ by the formula $\phi(x, v) = (x, \Phi(x)v)$.

Atiyah claims that equipping $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ with "the usual topology" makes $\Phi$ continuous. I'm trying to figure out what topology he means. My naive guess was the compact open topology, but I couldn't figure out how to show that $\Phi$ was continuous in this case. I noticed that for every $v \in V$, the map $x \mapsto \Phi(x)v$ is continuous. Could Atiyah be talking about a weak topology of some kind?

If it helps, later on in the passage he claims that $\mathrm{Iso}(V,W)$, the set of linear isomorphisms between $V$ and $W$ is an open subset of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ with this topology.

Comment: $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ is a finite-dimensional (complex?) vector space. There is a unique topology on each finite-dimensional vector space making it into a topological vector space.

Comment: I didn't know this fact about topological vector spaces, but I found a reference for it. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't see how to show that the map $\Phi: X \to \mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ is continuous. I thought it would be easier once I assumed $V$ and $W$ were normable TVS, but I can't see how.

Comment: For each fixed $v\in V$, the map $x\mapsto \Phi(x)v$ is the composition of  $\phi$ with the second-coordinate projection, so $\Phi$ is weak-* continuous (this is valid for infinite dimension as well). By @LordSharktheUnknown's comment, this vector topology on $Hom(V,W)$ is the same as any other (e.g. Euclidean topology in matrix, operator, strong,...).